# Sql Server 2005 AutoCompletion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know whether SQLServer 2005 provide auto completion when typing stuff in??

I ve looked in the options many times but cannot find this option which is suprising as a lot of other sql editors do support this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not. Intellisence is well in Sql server 2008, or you can look at RedGate.

[RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/) and

[SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

No. Intellisense only comes in SQL Server 2008, provided that both the server and the client tools are 2008.

There are 3rd party tools that'll give you what you want, tho, such as [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)